# how to build a dictionary from the fetch request array result?

Tags: swift, core-data, swift3, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsfetchrequest

I have stumbled on setting up a table view with a number of sections based on an entity attribute and the num. of cells based on another attribute of the same entity. I have an entity called Floors (more than one instance can exist) and this has 2 attributes: floor number and number of rooms on the floor. I have performed a fetch request and it return the array. My knowledge is not good enough to figure how to set up a dictionary like this: [floorNumber: numberOfRoomsInFloor] so I can take it and define the number of sections in table and the number of rows in each section. I have tried and failed and I did had a look at threads on the site but I don't really see a solution that could work for me. If someone could take a bit of time and help me out it would mean a lot to me. Please have a look at my code below:

```
class RoomAndAlarmTypeTableVC: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

//MARK: - Properties

private var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext!

private var storedFloors = [Floors]()

private var floorsAndRooms = [String: String]()

//MARK: - Actions

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    loadFloorData()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

private func loadFloorData() {
    let floorRequest: NSFetchRequest<Floors> = Floors.fetchRequest()
    do {
        storedFloors = try managedObjectContext.fetch(floorRequest)
        print("\(storedFloors)")

    } catch {
        print("could not load data from core \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}



// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return storedFloors.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let specificFloor = storedFloors[section]
    return Int(specificFloor.numberOfRooms)
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "house cell", for: indexPath) as! ViewRooomNumberCell
    let tableSections = storedFloors[indexPath.section]
    let floorItem = tableSections.numberOfRooms[indexPath.row]
    let floorNumber = String(floorItem.numberOfRooms)
    cell.floorNumberTxt.text = floorNumber
    return cell
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the storedFloors contains all the floors (which are sections) you should not need the dictionary, and just use:

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return storedFloors.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
// this will return the proper number of rows (rooms) for each section
    return storedFloors[section].numberOfRooms
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for taking the time to help me. but i have a fatal error which says "index out of bounds" when i run your implementation. could you please tell me why?

Comment: can you post the exact code that gives you the error?

Comment: override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return Int(storedFloors[section - 1].numberOfRooms) // index out of range
    }

Comment: my bad: replace section - 1 with section (already edited in the answer). That should do

Comment: thank you for your help, it works. have a nice day sir.

Comment: the implementation that I have helped with yesterday does not do the job unfortunately. if I have two floors declared (0 and 1) in the picker the number of rooms gets assigned only if the first item in the picker is selected.  the second problem is with the table view. if for floor 0 i assigned 1 room I get only one row with number 1 inside. I have modified the function but now i get an error of "type 16 has no subscript member". type 16 being the type of the attribute inside the db. I have edited the code. Could you please take a bit of time and help me? Thank you

Comment: i have posted another question on the site with a bit more detail. please see below: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43018513/uitableview-not-displaying-the-correct-number-of-sections-and-rows-from-the-fetc