# UITableView not displaying the correct number of sections and rows from the fetch request array result

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3, uipickerview, nsfetchrequest

I think my problem spans over multiple VC.
In the table VC I perform a fetch request that returns an array of Floor objects. This entity has 2 attributes (floor number and number of rooms in floors). If I assign 2 floors (0 and 1) it works and prints them. The next VC contains a picker that displays the number of floors and a text box that is used to assign the number of rooms per floor. There must be a problem with this function because it gets called only if the first item of the picker is selected (prints the result). If I have 2 floors (0 and 1 in the picker) and floor 1 is selected the function does not assign the room value to any other floor. It doesn't matter how many floors, the function will only work for the first one. I have looked of how to modify the function but did not find any suitable solutions. 
The second problem is that the table view does only display one row. Lets say that for floor 0 I assign 1; than only a row with 1 appears. If anyone could help me it would mean a lot to me. Thank you 
Please see the code below for the picker function:

```
 @IBAction func setTheFloors(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if storedFloors.count > 0 {
        if storedFloors.first?.floorNumber == pickedFloor! {
            storedFloors.first?.numberOfRooms = roomNumberValue
            print("\(storedFloors.first?.floorNumber) + \(storedFloors.first?.numberOfRooms)")
        }
    }
    do {
        try managedObjectContext.save()
    } catch {
        fatalError("could not save context because: \(error)")
    }

}


@IBAction func nextStep(_ sender: UIButton) {

}

private func loadFloorData() {
    let floorRequest: NSFetchRequest<Floors> = Floors.fetchRequest()
    do {
        storedFloors = try managedObjectContext.fetch(floorRequest)
    } catch {
        print("could not load data from core \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}

private func spinnerItems() {
    for i in 0...floorValue! - 1 {
        convertedFloorValues.append(String(i))
    }
}
```

and this section of code is for the table view.

```
class RoomAndAlarmTypeTableVC: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

//MARK: - Properties

private var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext!

private var storedFloors = [Floors]()

private var floorsAndRooms = [String: String]()

//MARK: - Actions

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    loadFloorData()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

private func loadFloorData() {
    let floorRequest: NSFetchRequest<Floors> = Floors.fetchRequest()
    do {
        storedFloors = try managedObjectContext.fetch(floorRequest)
        print("\(storedFloors)")

    } catch {
        print("could not load data from core \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}



// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return storedFloors.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let specificFloor = storedFloors[section]
    return Int(specificFloor.numberOfRooms)
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "house cell", for: indexPath) as! ViewRooomNumberCell
    let tableSections = storedFloors[indexPath.section]
    let floorItem = tableSections.numberOfRooms[indexPath.row]
    let floorNumber = String(floorItem.numberOfRooms)
    cell.floorNumberTxt.text = floorNumber
    return cell
}
```

}

Comment: which type is numberOfFloors? You are using subscripts on it tableSections.numberOfRooms[indexPath.row] but this does not seem to match with the code above

Comment: numberOfRooms is of type Int 16 as declared in the entity attribute

Comment: i found this implementation as a way to make the sections and rows. before it did not work ..if i had a floor with 2 rooms. it would only display 1 row with the value 2 ..

Comment: then if numberOfRooms is not an array, your code above won't even compile.. if the floor numbers are just sequential, you might as well use indexPath.row (maybe adding 1 if you want to start from 1), since you are already setting the right number in numberOfRowsInSection.

Comment: you mean     let floorItem = tableSections[indexPath.row] ?

Comment: if what you want to display is just sequential numbers for each room

Comment: alright. thank you